# How do I create a method binding a stored procedure in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

How do I create a function mapping a SQL stored procedure?

I have tried

```
var order = context.CustomerDetails.SqlQuery("DisplayTotalOrders @CustomerID", new SqlParameter("CustomerID", "1"));

var order = context.CustomerDetails.SqlQuery("DisplayTotalOrders @CustomerID", 1);
```

but nothing has worked.

Error message is shown as below. And this method seems quite an ad-hoc execution. Is there a way destined to create a method which binds a SQL Server stored procedure in EF? I am not talking about just INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE functions. I am referring to executing any SQL Server stored procedure.

> Unhandled Exception:
> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: The data
> reader is incompatible with the specified
> 'TestEF_Code.CustomerDetail'. A member of the type, 'CustomerID', does
> not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
> at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.GetMemberOrdinalFromReader(DbDataReader
> storeDataReader, EdmMember member, EdmType currentType, Dictionary`2 renameList)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.GetColumnMapsForType(DbDataReader storeDataReader, EdmType edmType, Dictionary`2 renameList)    at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.CreateColumnMapFromReaderAndType(DbDataReader
> storeDataReader, EdmType edmType, EntitySet entitySet, Dictionary`2 renameList)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.InternalTranslate[TElement](DbDataReader reader, String entitySetName, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, EntitySet& entitySet, TypeUsage& edmType)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryInternal[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass69`1.b__68()
> at
> System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass69`1.b__67()
> at
> System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryReliably[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.<>c__DisplayClass11.b__10()
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()    at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
> TestEF_Code.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> B:\Users\trio\Programming\TestEF-Code\TestEF-Code\Program.cs:line 17

Comment: afaik, if you want to use stored procedure you have to use database first approach.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Yes, I'm exactly using database first approach

Comment: Read the Exception message. It has useful information. It also means that "nothing has worked" isn't true. EF did execute the sproc (the first line is correct) but it doesn't match.

Comment: so it is the only and official way to go? i don't understand the error message. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: @TrioCheung i meant, you have to use `edmx` which automates parameter binding and stuff, see [this tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx) for a proper database-first approach. what you did is, waltzing with raw sql query invoking stored procedure - yes it can work, but it may cause a lot of headache. this question is hard to replicate given we dont know how the mapping looks like and how the stored procedure built. what we know is just `CustomerID` doesnt match with whatever stuff in `CustomerDetail` class.

Comment: I have done what i am told to add an ObjectResult method. But the ModelValidationException keeps prompting. It says EntityType 'xxx' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. I found somewhere that i have to annotate [Keyless]. but the attribute belongs to Asp.net core. My programming environment is .net framework4.8. it doesn't make any sense. So how do I fix this?